# SQL script to show posts from groups where user is member

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB with the following tables(Irrelevant table columns are not included):
cs_member - *member_id
cs_group - *group_id
cs_post - *post_id, group_id, member_id, content, likes, comments, anonymous
cs_group_member - group_id, member_id

I need an sql-script which shows only posts from groups where the logged in user is a member.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a great project! Let us know when you have a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying you need help writing

```
Select ...
From cs_post
Inner Join cs_group_member On cs_post.group_id = cs_group_member.group_id
Where cs_group_member.member_id = $MY_MEMBER_ID
```

What do you do for a living, and why are you asking this?

Comment: I'm a student and it's for a school project, why are you asking?

Comment: This site is not for others to do your homework from scratch -- although it looks like I already did. It's simply rude. It doesn't look like you even tried. If you do try, and get stuck, post a question like 'I'm trying to do this, and this is what I've tried so far, and these are the errors/problems I have'.

Comment: To clarify: people here love _helping_, but not doing work others don't feel like doing. In any case, you're welcome.

Comment: I understand that. however, I have been sitting for hours scratching my head at this. I am also not the brightest when it comes to SQL, which is why, instead of wasting more hours, I decided to ask here. This project is big and I will need to use similar queries in the future.
What you did was not my "homework", but you helped me understand more about sql queries. So thank you for that